# web service - web client function will not write to db

Tags: wcf, web-services

I am unable to write any records to my database using a web service.  Service is set up OK and can access it via uri and also query my database via the service using a simple page i created.

When it comes to writing to the database, I am not getting any errors, and the instance of my WebClient which is populated with variables to write to the db is holding all the variables OK but when it comes to actually writing to the db (see below code) nothing seems to happen except that the Member ID of the last existing member added to the database is returned.

```
        'assign all abMem fields to values within form to write to database
        newMem.Title = ddTitle.SelectedValue
        newMem.Initials = txtInitials.Text
        newMem.Surname = txtSurname.Text
        newMem.Address1 = txtAdd1.Text
        newMem.Address2 = txtAdd2.Text
        newMem.Address3 = txtAdd3.Text
        'etc etc .... additional fields have been removed

        Try
            cc.Open()
            cc.CreateMember(newMem)
            returnMem = cc.GetMember(newMem)
            MesgBox(returnMem.MemberID & " - Member Created")
            cc.Close()
        Catch cex As CommunicationException
            MesgBox("CommEX - " & cex.Message)
            cc.Abort()
        Catch tex As TimeoutException
            MesgBox("TimeEX - " & tex.Message)
            cc.Abort()
        Finally
            MesgBox("Closed the Client")
        End Try
```

When i run the above, I've noticed in the log file for the service (in the system32 folder on my server) that 2 requests are made each time - presumably one for where I am trying to add a record and the other I would think would be the request for the ID of this member (which isn't created, hence why I believe it it is simply returning the last successful entry in the table).

I know there isn't a problem with the actual web service as there is another user successfully able to add to the db via the service (unfortunately I am unable to simply copy their set-up as they are hitting it via a php page) so i know there is a problem somewhere in my code.

Is `cc.CreateMember(newMem)` the correct syntax for passing a member's details to the function in the webservice is what I am wondering?

Comment: Do you not need to do a `cc.SaveChanges` when you use `cc.CreateMember` method?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, no. 'CreateMember' is the name of a function in my actual service which queries the database with the details of the new member (passed from my test page) to see if this member already exists (by name and address etc...) if the member does not exist the service should run a simple insert, but this part of the service is not running (as far as I can see).

Comment: Sorry for some reason i weas thinking entity framework instead of service call.  I assume you have stepped through this in debug mode and it is actually making the call?  If so then it would seem the failure must lie ine the service itself.

Comment: It seems to be calling the function OK, as I said the instance of the WebClient is populated with values as expected, and I am not seeing any errors or exceptions when it gets to the line `cc.CreateMember(newMem)` - although I am guessing this is where the problem must lie as other users are able to hit the service and add a record to the database OK...

Comment: Does the db user have priviledges to write to the database?

Comment: I dont know how to tell what you need to pass without looking at the wsdl or service code.  Is this service something you have access too that you could run it locally and debug it?

Comment: I do have access to the service so with a little bit of work I could have something set up to debug.  Can you tell me what code you want to see and I can post it? (Presumably just the CreateMember function?)

Comment: in response to oleksii - yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-wrote the code (seems identical to above) and republished the web service.  Seems to be working OK now so I must have had some silly mistake somewhere!